# How can you tell when a Trello card is saved?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

There is no save button. How can I tell if the Trello card is saved or not?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What action are you trying to take?

Comment: I open a card, add a field with some data, then usually there is a Save button and I click it. Then I close that card. Has my card been saved? There is no Save button for the card, and if I click outside the card, it closes. I find I keep opening the card to see if what I just put in was saved.

Comment: No answers have been given so I will assume it's just the way the Trello interface works. I will assume I can trust that the card is saved when I close it after adding or changing a field. It would be nice if the Trello docs mentioned this. They say "Cards are the basic unit of a board." But it appears that fields are the basic controllable unit. You actually cannot save a card explicitly. It just sort of continues on with its ghostly non-save-able existence.

Comment: Every change is saved immediately after entering, isn't it? What kind of changes do you mean?

Comment: It appears that the changes to the fields of the card are saved immediately. But for some reason I do not trust that they will be there when I open that card again. I think I expect dialog box behavior, like in a desktop application. Usual dialog box behavior is, you change a field or two inside of a dialog box, and then if you close the box, it asks if you want to save what you changed before closing the dialog.

Comment: A Trello card seems like a dialog box to me. But it does not work like one, so it confuses me a bit. I do not know if I can trust that my changes to the field of the card will be there the next time I open the card. I suppose I will just have to get used to it.

Answer (score 2):

Most things on a card will have a "Save" button. In addition to that, other items, such as editing labels or assigning members, will display a tick or checkmark (✔) next to the action you've just completed.

For the most part, when the card content changes, it will autosave.

Sometimes, if you hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> on a field, or close it before it has a chance to save, you will see a note like this:

> You have unsaved edits on this field. View edits or discard.

You can then make sure your edits are saved to the card before moving onto your next task.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is a little scary to me that I could write some content and it *might* be saved or I *might* see the warning "You have unsaved edits..." I wish there was a way to ensure it is always saved, like a Google Doc is.